# How to get KerrasRegressor to work? I keep getting an AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to optimize hyperparameters for a simple sequential neural-network using the KerasRegressor as part of a learning exercise. This is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer

'''CREATE THE MODEL'''
def design_model(features):
    model = Sequential(name = "My_Sequential_Model") 
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(features.shape[1],))) 
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu')) 
    model.add(Dense(1)) 
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['mae'], optimizer=opt) 
    return model

'''TEST/PLOT THE MODEL: GRID SEARCH'''
def do_grid_search():
    batch_size = [6, 64]
    epochs = [10, 30, 61]
    model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=design_model, features=features_train) # KerasRegressor expects a function and not the model
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = make_scorer(mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False),return_train_score = True)
    grid_result = grid.fit(features_train, labels_train, verbose = 0)
    print(grid_result)
    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

    means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
    stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
    params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params): print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))

    print("Traininig")
    means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
    stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_train_score']
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params): print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))

print("-------------- GRID SEARCH --------------------")
do_grid_search()
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 732, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py", line 167, in fit
AttributeError: module 'keras.losses' has no attribute 'is_categorical_crossentropy'
```

What do I do? I am using Tensorflow 2.15 and Keras 2.15.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the issue. I had a go using `from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor`, which seems to be a replacement for `from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor`. Not sure if it's a data issue at your end, or a package issue. Worth trying `scikeras` perhaps - it's mostly a swap-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

As per user3128 I solved the issue by using `scikeras` instead:

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
```

Then the rest of the code is the same.